# Difference between finite volume, characteristic method and plug flow models of a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, differential-equations

I have to model pipes (of a district heating network) with ODE's.
My background is computer-science, so it is not that easy for me to understand different approaches.

- [Finite volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) approach.
- [Method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).
- [Plug-Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_flow) model of a pipe.

I don't have to understand each approach in detail - but it would help a lot to have a good overview. Some in my group think, that the method of characteristics is the same as the plug-Flow approach, is that true?

Would be really great, if someone could help.

Comment: What exactly are you modelling? Will you do this analytically or numerically? I ask this because FV is a numerical approach, while as i understand it MC and PF are analytical approaches.

Comment: Hey, thank you! We will do this numerically - as I understand (in our context) all 3 should be nummerical approaches

Comment: but what are you modelling exactly? You say 'pipes (of a district heating network)' but is that fluid flow (laminar/turbulent) combined with heat transfer in pipes? FV is applicable to any PDE, while MC and PF are applicable only to linear PDEs.

Comment: thanks: We want to calculate: fluid flow, temperatures at each node, pressure at each node. So is there a difference between MC and PF?

Answer (score 2):

The Finite Volume Method, and Method of Characteristics are both ways to go about solving partial differential equations.

The Finite Volume Method is a way to take complicated geometry that would be impossible or difficult to model analytically and break it into regions that adhere to geometry that is easy to model analytically such as tetrahedrons. The partial differential equations are solved on these simple geometries and then the boundary conditions knit them together.

The Method of Characteristics is an analytical method of transforming partial differential equations into forms that are easily solved. This requires the original problem to be posed analytically. This method could be used to solve the simple geometries produced by the finite volume method.

Plug Flow is a method that is specific to flow of fluids through pipes. It makes the assumption that a pipe can be treated as one dimensional, and the internals of a given cross section can be abstracted away. For example rather than having a velocity vector field, and a temperature field for every cross sectional slice of the pipe, you can simplify each cross section down to a point such that you only have an average velocity, an area, and a temperature at each point along a pipe.

All three of these methods could be combined, for example, your pipes could be segmented (Finite Volume Method) into constant area sections, and joints, which could each be modeled using an analytical plug flow PDE using the method of characteristics.

Comment: (+1) Good answer.  Could you elaborate on MC?  Admittedly, in my little exposure to MC, I am aware of of its use in supersonic flow ([example](http://aerodynamics.aeromech.usyd.edu.au/gasdynamics_w.php?page=9&)).  Is it evaluating the PDE's at points, or along  curves of constant parameter values?

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified to elaborate much. From the reading I've done. It looks like the method of characteristics allows you to calculate values along curves in particular directions. However, it seems you can only get solutions at the intersections of these characteristic lines. So if you have characteristic lines that are defined analytically and continuously you would have a complete solution over the domain. However, the method can also be used discretely such that you use the characteristic lines to segment up complex geometry...

Comment: In this case one could say that the method of characteristics is an alternative to the Finite Volume Method, but I think the finite volume method is really an umbrella term, that could probably cover using the method of characteristics in this manner. @theNamesCross

Comment: Most FVM I've seen use square cuboids, not tetrahedrons.

Comment: @KyleKanos yes cuboid elements typically will result in a better result with fewer degrees of freedom. However, last I heard, algorithms to map arbitrary geometries to a cuboid mesh were still severely limited, only working for simple geometry, whereas automatic tetrahedron meshes have been around for decades. Both have important roles in FVM.

Comment: Like I said, my experience is that FVM uses cubiods, added to that, I typically see that FEM uses tetrahedrons. As to arbitrary geometries, AMR has been around for decades as well.